# Java 2 players on 1 Keyboard using AWSD AND the arrows

Tags: java

I am making a game in java and it is working fine. But the thing is, when I spawn 2 players on the map and I am moving 1 player the other player is going synchronously. I want that player1 uses (AWSD) and player2 uses the arrows.

This is the code I have right now for the Class: "KeyInput"

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        //If the special key is pressed, set it to true.
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) handler.setUp(true);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) handler.setDown(true);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) handler.setLeft(true);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) handler.setRight(true);

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_I) handler.setUp(true);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_K) handler.setDown(true);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_J) handler.setLeft(true);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_L) handler.setRight(true);
    }
    //If the pressed key is released, set everything to false.
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        //If the special key is released, put it to false.
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) handler.setUp(false);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) handler.setDown(false);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) handler.setLeft(false);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) handler.setRight(false);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_P) handler.setDropBomb(true);

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_I) handler.setUp(false);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_K) handler.setDown(false);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_J) handler.setLeft(false);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_L) handler.setRight(false);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_M) handler.setDropBomb(true);    
    }
```

In the class: "Player" the code is as followed:

```
public Player(int x, int y, ID id, Handler handler, Game game, SpriteSheet ss) {
        super(x, y, id, ss);
        this.handler = handler;
        this.game = game;

        //Get the player image of the SpriteSheet
        player_image= ss.grabImage(1,1,32,48);
    }

    public void tick() {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;

        collision();

        //Set the movement of the player: left,right,up,down
        if(handler.isUp()) velY = -5;
        else if(!handler.isDown()) velY = 0;

        if(handler.isDown()) velY = 5;
        else if(!handler.isUp()) velY = 0;

        if(handler.isRight()) velX = 5;
        else if(!handler.isLeft()) velX = 0;

        if(handler.isLeft()) velX = -5;
        else if(!handler.isRight()) velX = 0;

        if(handler.isDropped()){
            Dropbomb(x,y);
        }

    }
```

I've been thinking on this for ages.. I have tried to make a second handler but that resulted in alot of duplicate code. Somehow got an Idea?

Comment: With different controls you're going to need some "duplicate code"

Answer (score 0):

You need to deferienate which keys affect player1 and which keys affect player2.  Something like this:

```
    //If the special key is pressed, set it to true.
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) handler.setUpPlayer1(true);
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) handler.setDownPlayer1(true);
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) handler.setLeftPlayer1(true);
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) handler.setRightPlayer1(true);

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_I) handler.setUpPlayer2(true);
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_K) handler.setDownPlayer2(true);
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_J) handler.setLeftPlayer2(true);
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_L) handler.setRightPlayer2(true);
```

Or you could pass the player in as a variable:

```
...
if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) handler.setUp(true,1);
...
if(key == KeyEvent.VK_I) handler.setUp(true,2);
...
```

Or if you have global access to the player variables, like this:

```
...
if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) handler.setUp(true, Global.PLAYER_1);
...
if(key == KeyEvent.VK_I) handler.setUp(true, Global.PLAYER_2);
...
```

Comment: Then I have to make ( set methods for player1 and for player2 ) this is a bit dirty code I guess..

Comment: If you have the Player object you can just do player[1,2].setUp(true)